# C# - what is wrong with the code (generics, static method etc)

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm getting a "cannot convert from 'int' to 'TValue'" in the following code.  How can I fix this?  I understand why there is an issue, but I'm wonder the best way around this.  Do I need to make a decision to specific type the ReturnValuesDict, and not leave it generic?

```
public class ReturnValuesDict<TKey, TValue> : CloneableDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{

    public static ReturnValuesDict<TKey, TValue> CreateEmptyClone(ReturnValuesDict<TKey, TValue> current) 
    {
        var newItem = new ReturnValuesDict<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach (var curr in current)
        {
            newItem.Add(curr.Key, 0);  // ERROR on the 2nd parameter here
        }
        return newItem;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where does the 0 come from? What are you trying to accomplish? EDIT: I guess what I'm trying to say is, "What exactly is _empty_ supposed to mean?"

Comment: your problem is your method returns a generic collection (tkey,tvalue), but your trying to add a TValue with 0 (int), which kind of defeats the purpose of using generics in the first place. :) @Ani's answer is the way to go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason this does not compile is that 0 (an `int`) cannot, in general, be converted to the  dictionary-values' type (`TValue`), which, as far as the compiler is concerned, is some *arbitrary* type. (`where TValue : int` wouldn't work, but that's another matter)

I assume you're trying to construct a dictionary with the same keys as the original, but with 'empty' values?

If you are ok with what .NET considers to be the 'default' value of a type, you could try changing the line to:

```
newItem.Add(curr.Key, default(TValue));
```

This will use the [default-value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) of the dictionary-values' type. For example:`null` for reference-types, zero for numeric-value types.

If, on the other hand, the intention is to write a method that only works with dictionarys having `int`values, you could make it more restrictive (place this in another class):

```
public static ReturnValuesDict<TKey, int> CreateEmptyClone<TKey>(ReturnValuesDict<TKey, int> current) 
{
    var newItem = new ReturnValuesDict<TKey, int>();
    foreach (var curr in current)
    {
        newItem.Add(curr.Key, 0);  
    }
    return newItem;
}
```

Note that the method is now a generic method that takes an unconstrained generic`TKey`parameter.

Comment: Or if he wants, he can use `null` instead of 0 (which I think is his intention), provided the `TValue` is reference type. He can use `where` clause to state that.